# Creating ranking chart in Higcharts with bar range colors

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a ranking chart like this :

[ranking chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsiXe.jpg)

Where the color of the bar depends on the % of achievement from 0% to 100% in a test.

I cant find the way to use the same serie for different bar colors, and create a multi label legend with only 1 serie. I want to press the legend and show only the bars of that color.

EDIT:

Just figured our how to paint each bar, im OK formatting the data before creating my chart.

I will paste the new code, I only need to add the legend with any color info and filter.

CODE

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Ranking alumnos'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text:  'El color de la barra indica el nivel de logro'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo','Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo', 'Alumno de ejemplo'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Logro total %',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' %'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Logro %',
        data: [
            {y: 100 , color: '#aaff99'},   
            {y: 98, color: '#aaff99'}, 
            {y: 95 , color: '#aaff99'},   
            {y: 90, color: '#aaff99'}, 
            {y: 85 , color: '#aaff99'},   
            {y: 84, color: '#aaff99'}, 
            {y: 83 , color: '#aaff99'},   
            {y: 82, color: '#aaff99'}, 
            {y: 81, color: '#aaff99'}, 
            {y: 81 , color: '#aaff99'},

            {y: 75, color: 'yellow'}, 
            {y: 75 , color: 'yellow'},   
            {y: 74, color: 'yellow'}, 
            {y: 73 , color: 'yellow'},   
            {y: 70, color: 'yellow'},
            {y: 65, color: 'yellow'}, 
            {y: 64 , color: 'yellow'},   
            {y: 61, color: 'yellow'}, 
            {y: 61 , color: 'yellow'},   
            {y: 61, color: 'yellow'} ,

            {y: 60, color: 'orange'}, 
            {y: 60 , color: 'orange'},   
            {y: 58, color: 'orange'}, 
            {y: 56 , color: 'orange'},   
            {y: 54, color: 'orange'},
            {y: 53, color: 'orange'}, 
            {y: 53 , color: 'orange'},   
            {y: 51, color: 'orange'}, 
            {y: 51 , color: 'orange'},   
            {y: 51, color: 'orange'},

            {y: 50, color: 'red'}, 
            {y: 50 , color: 'red'},   
            {y: 49, color: 'red'}, 
            {y: 48 , color: 'red'},   
            {y: 48, color: 'red'},
            {y: 48, color: 'red'}, 
            {y: 46 , color: 'red'},   
            {y: 46, color: 'red'}, 
            {y: 46 , color: 'red'},   
            {y: 46, color: 'red'} 




        ]
    }]
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/re0q5fnv/

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like.. (i tried it in your jsfiddle)

```
legend: {

        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    }


series: [{
        name: 'Logro orange  %',
        color: 'red'
        },{
        name: 'Logro orange  %',
        color: 'orange'
        },{
        name: 'Logro yellow %',
        color: 'yellow',
        data: [ <your data>]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! , but what I need is 1 bar per 'Alumno de ejemplo' instead of 3 bars , just like the graph I posted at the beginning.